# A problem occurred evaluating project ':libphonenumber_plugin'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, libphonenumber

I have been using the flutter_libphonenumber package, but I keep getting the below error. I have tried updating Flutter SDK and Gradle versions and resetting the app version.

- Flutter Version: 3.16.4
- Android SDK version: 34.0.0

Package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libphonenumber

[image]